# Using the coordinates of two of a triangle's vertices to calculate the coordinates of the third

Tags: trigonometry

I know two coordinates of two vertices in a triangle (not aligned to an axis) and I'm attempting to calculate the coordinates of the third.

```
          a
     B ------- C
       \      |
        \     |
C'       \    |
        c \   | b
           \  |
            \ |
             \|
              A
```

I know the coordinates of **A** and **B**, the lengths of **a** and **c**, and that the angle **C** will always be a right angle. I believe there can only be two possible solutions for the coordinates of **C**; the one drawn above, and one with **C** reflected about the line **c**, approximately at **C'**. I'd like to calculate both positions.

**EDIT**:

The source of the triangle is as below.

[image: Valid XHTML]

I know the apex **A**, the centre of the circle **B**, the radius of the circle (**a**) and, from Pythag with (**B - A**), I know the length of **c**. I'm trying to find the points at which a line from the apex are at a tangent to each side of the circle, **C** and **C'**.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1351794/1198585) appears to be an answer to my problem; can anyone elaborate on 'Given two sides of a right triangle, it's easy to find the length and direction of the third side.'.

Comment: Is it always going to be a right-angle triangle?

Comment: @minitech I would guess so, or else this question wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: Do you know about http://math.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @minitech Yes, angle C will always be a right angle.

Answer (score 1):

> I know the coordinates of A and B, and the lengths of a and c. From this, I believe there can only be two possible solutions for the coordinates of C

This is not true.  There are an infinite number of choices for the position of C, as you don't know the length of b.

For example:

```
C
| 
| 
| 
| 
| 
B
\      
 \     
  \    
c  \   
    \  
     \ 
      \
       A
```

If you connect C to A, you still maintain those known lengths....

In order for this to be true, you would also need to know one of the angles (such as that it's a right triangle), or the length of b.

Comment: C will always be a right angle. Sorry, I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy: As the C angle is PI/2 then `b=sqrt(c*c-a*a)` so you know the lengths of a, b, c.

The coordinates of C and C' = the intersections of two circles:

1. center B radius a
2. center A radius b

Solved here for example //A=P1, B=P0, C=P3: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187107/calculate-coordinates-of-3rd-point-vertex-of-a-scalene-triangle-if-angles-and

The essential condition for this: `if (a<c)` otherwise it has no solution.

Answer (score -1):

If you know it's going to be a right triangle, then you know the x and y values will be taken from the other two points.

```
Point coordsForCompletingTriangleTop(Point a, Point b) {
    return new Point(a.x,b,y);
}

Point coordsForCompletingTriangleBottom(Point a, Point b) {
    return new Point(b.x,a,y);
}
```

If cannot be guaranteed that it will be a right triangle, then you do need more information. The length of B, the length of C, or the angle of BCA would be required.

Comment: The triangle isn't (necessarily) aligned to the axis; your answer doesn't take into account rotation?

Comment: You have to assume axis aligned otherwise there isn't a unique result

Comment: As I said in the original post, I'm not looking for a unique solution; I'm looking for both solutions. I need both possible coordinates of C.

Comment: @user mine will give you that *if* you can assume that the triangle you want is aligned with the axis. That is to say that `AC` is parallel to the Y axis and `AB` is parallel to the X axis. What Rezzie is saying is that without that assumption, it might be rotated around, and the coordinates of C could be at an infinite number of different places.

Comment: @user also keep in mind that mine will provide you with a 0 area triangle for any points provided that form a line parallel to either axis.

Comment: @corsiKa I've updated the original question with a diagram (linked) explaining what I'm trying to achieve, that might make the situation clearer? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you assume a and b are the opposite corners of a rectangle

```
a = (xa, ya)
b = (xb, yb)
```

then the top right rectangle point is `c1 = (max(xa,xb), max(ya,yb))`
and the bottom left rectangle point is `c2 = (min(xa,xb), min(ya,yb))`

Assuming that `xa != xb` and `ya != yb`

```
                    (xa, ya) A              C1 (max(xa, xb), max(ya, yb))
                               o----------o
                               |\         |
                               | \        |
                               |  \       |
                               |   \      |
                               |    \     |
                               |     \    |
                               |      \   |
                               |       \  |
                               |        \ |
                               o----------o
(min(xa, xb), min(ya, yb)) C2               B (xb, yb)
```

If your diagonal is going the other way (to test this see if xa > xb) you need to swap min for max on the x

```
(min(xa, xb), max(ya, yb))  C3              A'
                               o----------o
                               |         /|
                               |        / |
                               |       /  |
                               |      /   |
                               |     /    |
                               |    /     |
                               |   /      |
                               |  /       |
                               | /        |
                               o----------o
                           B'               C4 (max(xa, xb), min(ya, yb))
```

And if you're interested, the full set of solutions actually lies on the circle:

[image: Set of solutions]

To compute this, suppose we have two points `A = (xa, ya)` and `B = (xb, yb)`. Then the center point of this circle is `c = (0.5 (xa + xb), 0.5 (ya + yb))` - just the midpoint of the A and B. The radius of the circle is `r = sqrt( (xb - xa)^2 + (yb - ya)^2) / 2` - using pythagoras' theorem to get the length of the line and halving it. Then any point on the circle can be defined by `p = c + (rcos(u), rsin (u))` for some angle `u`. There are 2 angles which give you the points `p = A` and `p = B` so these values of `u` are not good solutions. You can write out the equation and solve it for these 2 points to give you the values of u which you cannot use.

Comment: The length of (a,c) is fixed, there are only two solutions, see the image attached to question.

Comment: The question actually changed after a number of comments were made. The original question assumed there was 1 line joining 2 points. and the second and third line were unknown. If 2 sides of a right angle triangle are known, trivial pythagoras solves the problem.