# Finding the tangent point of a circle, connected to another point on the plane

Tags: openscad

If I have a circle of radius x with known coordinates for the center of the circle, and another point P on the coordinate grid, how do I find two coordinates points on the circle so that they create two tangent lines when connected to P?

I don't want a code sample, rather I just need to steps to figure it out myself :)

(I already saw the other answers on other questions, but those don't go into detail about how it works)

Comment: As you indicated that this is not really an OpenSCAD question, this sounds like pretty much a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351746/find-a-tangent-point-on-circle

Comment: As i said, they didn't explain properly